# onOrientationChanged() is being called when OrientationEventListener is disabled

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, orientation, lifecycle

I'm having an issue with an `OrientationEventListener` reporting events even after I have disabled it.

I am working with three fragments in a tab layout, and only one of the fragments needs orientation changes. When I move away from this fragment, I want the orientation events to stop having an effect.

The lifecycle portion of my code is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (orientationEventListener == null)
    {
        Log.w(LogTags.MOBILE_MONITOR, "Creating orientationListener in " + this.toString());
        orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(getActivity(), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int angle) {

                ...Do work using getActivity()...

            }
        };
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    orientationEventListener.enable();    
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    orientationEventListener.disable();
}
```

The problem comes when I switch the fragment while moving the device. When I try to call `getActivity()` in `onOrientationChanged(int angle)` of the `OrientationEventListener`, the call returns null, which means I get a null pointer exception if I try to use it.

While I could add a null check here, I just want to know why I am getting an orientation event when I have clearly disabled the listener. If I inspect the `OrientationEventListener` at the point of failure, it even reports `mEnabled=false`. Is there any way to prevent the event being propagated to my listener?

Comment: Hi Sleeke, have u found any solution for this. I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the orientation to `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`, the activity will be automatically rotated by the physical orientation sensor. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation

Solve this by resetting the orientation mode for the activity. For example, reset to the default portrait layout:

```
mOrientationEventListener.disable();
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```